# Google Schema button not showing up when testing

Tags: google-schemas

I'm testing my schema button by sending to myself (I am overriding the 
"From" email header address with my gmail address to test from the server that sends the email). Both recipient and sender are my gmail email address.

The schema shows up when I view the original email, but I don't see any buttons in my inbox.

Here is the script tag I am sending as part of my HTML email template:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "description": "User invited you to a test1.",
    "action": {
        "@type": "ConfirmAction",
        "name": "Accept",
        "handler": {
            "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
            "url": "http://localhost/?id=xxx"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is a screenshot of my inbox -- notice there is no "Accept" Gmail Action anywhere:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the email itself, also not "Accept Gmail Action anywhere:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the sender to be your own email address and your emails to be signed with DKIM or SPF in order for Gmail to render the action. It seems like you are trying to "fake" your email address which is exactly what we need to prevent.

Comment: Actually you don't for testing need the DKIM or SPF at least according to their docs. As long as sender/receiver are your gmail account it *should* work.

Comment: You need signing even when sending emails to yourself, otherwise anyone could spoof those emails.

Comment: Ok, it says "All emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the registration requirements and can be used for self-testing." which lead me to believe I don't need the DKIM or SPF.

Comment: Got it, we should probably make it clearer in the docs. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: If I use DKIM/SPF can I still spoof the sender to be my gmail account? Otherwise I have no idea how to actually email myself the content for testing.

Comment: DKIM/SPF is used to prevent spoofing, with it you can prove the email sender is the actual sender. You can connect to Gmail via SMTP to send emails from your account. I'm also going to add a small tutorial to the docs showing how to use Apps Script to send a signed email to yourself, please stay tuned.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I guess I have to come up with another way to test.

Comment: I can't send the true email without using my system. But you require SPF/DKIM validation (which we are adding) to even test it and at the same time the to/from email to be the same gmail account (which SPF/DKIM forbids). So I don't see how I can actually send you a test email as part of the registration.

Comment: Try with the Apps Script tutorial we just published: https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial

Comment: Ok, do you care if the registration email I send you is the production version html, or are you only interested in the schema data being identical.

Comment: It is better if you can send a real production email when applying for the registration, it helps us understand your use case.

Comment: I tested using my personal account and worked fine, but I'm having this problem when using in my company account. It's appearing that maestro.bounces.google.com sent the email. Some suggestion here?